# C++17 conditional (ternary) operator inconsistency between MSVC and Clang/GCC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, language-lawyer

The following code compiles under Clang/GCC under the C++17 standard, but does not compile under MSVC with `-std:C++17 /Zc:ternary`.

```cpp
struct CStringPtr
{
    const char *m_pString = nullptr;

    CStringPtr() = default;
    CStringPtr( const char *pString ) : m_pString( pString ) { }

    operator const char *() const { return m_pString; }
};

int main( int argc, char ** )
{
    bool b = !!argc;

    const char *X = b ? CStringPtr( "inside" ) : "naked";
    const char *Y = b ? "naked" : CStringPtr( "inside" );
    CStringPtr Z = b ? CStringPtr( "inside" ) : "naked";
    CStringPtr W = b ? "naked" : CStringPtr( "inside" );

    // Silence unused-variable warnings.
    return X && Y && Z && W;
}
```

Link to godbolt's compiler explorer with all three: https://godbolt.org/z/6d5Mrjnd7

MSVC emits an error for each of those four lines:

```
<source>(19): error C2445: result type of conditional expression is ambiguous: types 'const char [6]' and 'CStringPtr' can be converted to multiple common types
<source>(19): note: could be 'const char *'
<source>(19): note: or       'CStringPtr'
```

Whereas Clang/GCC each call the CStringPtr constructor for the naked string for all four of those cases.

In the [MSVC /Zc:ternary documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-ternary?view=msvc-160) they claim that the flag enables standards-compliant resolution of the ternary operator, which implies that either there's a bug in MSVC's implementation or Clang/GCC are not standards-compliant here.

The one other note here is that the MSVC docs mention an exception in this exact case with respect to the `const char *` type being used:

> An important exception to this common pattern is when the type of the operands is one of the null-terminated string types, such as const char*, const char16_t*, and so on. You can also reproduce the effect with array types and the pointer types they decay to. The behavior when the actual second or third operand to ?: is a string literal of corresponding type depends on the language standard used. C++17 has changed semantics for this case from C++14.

So, is MSVC non-compliant under C++17 rules? Or are Clang/GCC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Core issue 1805](https://wg21.link/CWG1805), which changed `?:` to decay arrays and functions to pointers before testing whether the other operand can be converted to it. The example in that issue is basically the one in your question:

> ```
>   struct S {
>     S(const char *s);
>     operator const char *();
>   };
>
>   S s;
>   const char *f(bool b) {
>     return b ? s : "";   // #1
>   }
> ```
>
> One might expect that the expression in #1 would be ambiguous, since
> `S` can be converted both to and from `const char*`. However, the
> target type for the conversion of `s` is `const char[1]`, not `const char*`, so that conversion fails and the result of the
> conditional-expression has type `S`.

It appears that neither GCC nor Clang implements that issue resolution, so they are still testing whether `CStringPtr` can be converted to an array.

If you manually decay the string literals with a unary `+`, everyone rejects the example as ambiguous.